# How to solve a system of 2nd degree boolean equations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, propositional-calculus, quadratics, boolean-algebra

Any ideas on how to solve a system of boolean equations with XOR(+) and AND(*) operations, that can contain `x[i] AND x[j]` (2nd degree), but not `x[i] AND x[j] AND x[k]` (i.e. no 3rd and above degree)?

More formally the system is like the following (all equations must be true simultaneously):

```
x[1] + x[2]*x[3] + x[3] + x[4]*x[5] = b[1]
x[1]*x[2] + x[3]*x[4] + x[5] = b[2]
... etc ...
```

Here `b[i]` is either `0` or `1`. Of course, in the solution `x[i]` is also `0` or `1` (it's all boolean).

Comment: Ken Thompson said "When in doubt, use brute force". If you have a moderate number of variables you can exhaustively test all combinations.

Comment: Brute force is not an option - no doubt :) . The number of `x[i]` is about 100. The number of equations is about the same.

Comment: Ok, then the way to go here is to use algebraic geometry. Your system of equations generates an ideal
$$
\langle x_1+x_2x_3+x_3+x_4x_5-b_1,x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5-b_2,\ldots\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_2[x_1,\ldots,x_n].
$$
Using [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) computations in this ideal you can solve the system via the so called _elimination ideals_. This process needs more theory than an answer here allows, but a good reference is _Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms_ by Cox, Little, and O'Shea.

Comment: You could use the tools `bc2cnf` and `cryptominisat` as described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2400990/58610).